# issues in swagger annotations with Yii2

Tags: php, annotations, yii2-advanced-app

I have 3 issues in swagger annotations with Yii2:

1. I want to add a key-like data into properties of swagger model schema of request format.

   ```
   /**
    @SWG\Property(name="profile",type="array",@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Profile"))
   */
   public $profile;

   /**
     @SWG\Property(name="device",type="array",@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Device"))
    */
   public $device;
   ```

   It will give me following json, and I want to add one key in this json

   ```
   "profile": [
       {
         "first_name": "string",
         "last_name": "string",
         "email": "string",
         "phone_number": "string",
         "profile_pic_url": "string"
       }
   ],
   "device": [
       {
         "id": "string",
         "os_name": "string",
         "os_version": "string"
       }
   ]
   ```
2. I want to remove the square brackets from the json object from model schema of request format on request format.
3. How do I use a single model having 3-4 api with different parameters? I want to know how I can utilize single model in 3-4 api because we are adding each attributes in property of swagger for swagger-ui.

Comment: Can you include the code from one of the things you have tried?

Comment: I edited your formatting and grammar to be more readable, but you're more likely to get someone to help if you show what you've already tried and how what you've tried has not helped.